# I get parse error code within my php code

Tags: php

I am trying to load my website but i get the error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE) in 
/var/www/html/dbconnect.php on line 17
```

Does anybody know what the problem is with line 17? I cant seem to find out

Php code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "db";
$username = "root";
$password = "philip123";

// Create connection

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT id, name, lastname, email FROM Students"
$result = $conn-> query($sql);

if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>". $row["id"] ."</td><td>". $row["name"] ."</td><td>".     $row["lastname"] ."</td><td>". $row["email"] ."</td></tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
}
else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn-> close();


?>
```

Line 17 is this line:
    $result = $conn-> query($sql);

Comment: add a semi colon after your SQL query variable.

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT id, name, lastname, email FROM Students"` missing the `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon at the line:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, lastname, email FROM Students"
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) im so blind haha

Comment: @Philip No problem :p

Comment: Get some basic code sniffer within editor to avoid this kind of stuff